# How to insert data from Kafka to Kudu using Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-kudu

I have a Spark streaming application that listens to a Kafka topic.
When getting the data I need to process it and send to Kudu.
Currently I am using `org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext API` and call the insert action with the data frame.
In order to create the data frame from my data I need to call `collect()` so I can create the data frame using sqlContext.

Is there a way to create the dataframe/insert the data into Kudu without calling `collect()` which is of course costly?

We are using Spark 1.6

Comment: Have you considered using Kafka Connect for this?

Comment: I am not familiar with this, will read about it, thanks.

Comment: In kafka connect can we define our process of how to convert the data from the topic ? in our case we need to do some calculation and processing before the data is ready for kudu.

Comment: The pattern to follow would be a streams processing application (e.g. Kafka Streams, KSQL, etc) would apply the transformation to the data and write that back to a Kafka topic. Kafka Connect then streams that topic to the target. Separation of responsibilities - easier to develop, operate, scale, etc :)

Answer (score 0):

Kudu sink for Spark now supports structured streaming: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KUDU-2640